# Visual Foxpro or VFP 9: Networking the database from a NAS drive

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro, nas

I am very new to VFP9 and need to move all the database files for a 6 user program to a Netgear ReadyNas Duo V2 shared network drive. I have moved the .dbc .dcx .dct .dbf .cdx and .fpt files to the Nas (\Nas-a0-3d-36\Daimler) but I don't know what to enter into the command window to permanentley tell the program how to locate the Nas drive path. None of the paths have been hard-coded that I am aware of.
Sorry I couldn't reply to previous suggestions so I had to start over again.
DRapp - Thanks for your help, when I followed your instructions and typed browse for objectType = "Table" the memo field results are: 15 little boxes then it says "members.dbf" with no path then 7 more boxes and "mbnumber" and one more box. 
Recompiled and now getting "Locate Database" error 'instantiating cursor object...' at start-up.

Many thanks

Comment: Yes I did forget the other backslash in the Nas path which should have been \\Nas-a0-3d-36\Daimler

Answer (score 0):

The program will save the database path somewhere, like in the Windows Registry, a .INI file, or a foxpro resource file. What was the prior path? Do a disk and registry search for that.

Comment: Thanks very much to all who have contributed with this. Unfortunately the networking project has been abandoned by my client so this info may at some time further down the track be used but not in the foreseeable future.I hope it may help somebody with a similar issue so that all your efforts & help were not wasted.Regards

Answer (score 0):

Browsing the DBC is good to see all the tables(DBF) that make up the database. The DBC will also list all the other supporting files such as the indexes(CDX) and memo files(fpt).

As long as you ensure that all the files listed in the DBC have been copied to the new location, including the DBC, DCX and DCT, the you are probably ok.

Once the files have been copied, you can start up VFP, go to the command window, and try the following:

```
 CD C:\mydirectory\mysubdir  &&navigate to new directory
 OPEN DATABASE myVFPDatabase EXCLUSIVE  &&Open the database exclusively
 VALIDATE DATABASE    &&This will display a message on the VFP screen to verify the database is OK
```

As far as the application not finding the database, you will have to look through the code for the command "OPEN DATA". One way to do this is to use the VFP "Task Pane -> Filer" to search for that string in the project.

Once you find the code that opens the database, change the path, recompile and test the app.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, "I get database container is valid". I did a browse of the dbc and it showed the names of the tables but I can't tell if any are missing and I couldn't see any links between the tables.

Comment: If you get the message that the container is valid, then you should be all set. If there was a problem, the message would say what the problem was. When you browse the DBC and see the table names, they should match what you see if you use Windows Explorer to view the files in the directory. Also, after you OPEN DATABASE mydatabase, you could do a MODIFY DATABASE to see a visual representation of the tables and relations in the database. Also, if you find these post useful, please be sure to mark the post as answered, etc...

Comment: I managed to compare an original of the database with the one I have now after doing the validate recover command and there were some indexes missing so I re-created them as identicle as I could to the original and it looks good except the ones I added aren't quite in the same order.
I can now get the program started if I bypass an error about a sales array not being valid right at the start and now access some of the databases on the Nas ok but it is full of errors when I try other functions that are connected with sales that were all working before the validate.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, all the USE statements could be hard coded for the path, which you believe is not the case. Another thing to consider is all forms have potential for cursors in the dataenvironment, which could be hard coded, or relatively pathed.

Related to Paul's suggestion: the application might use the SET PATH command to tell the programs where to look for files. Additionally, it could depend on a CONFIG.FPW file (internal to the EXE or external in the app folder, or directed by parameter passed to the EXE) where the PATH might be configured. Some programs also depend on the application shortcut in Windows for a StartIn folder.

Or it could be a combination of all these options.

Comment: Thanks to all who have helped with this.